# What is wrong with my ajax loading bar? Why does it not function correctly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want an AJAX process bar. Why when I press a button does the bar not perform any function?

When it post back to server the bar should appear? The bar appears at the top of my page.

Is the way I declare the `div` correct?

```
<style type="text/css">
    #loadingbar {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 2147483647;
      top: 0;
      left: -6px;
      width: 1%;
      height: 2px;
      background: #b91f1f;
      -moz-border-radius: 1px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
      border-radius: 1px;
      -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
      transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    }
    #loadingbar.waiting dd, #loadingbar.waiting dt {
      -moz-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
      -ms-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
      -o-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
      -webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
      animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
    }

    #loadingbar dt {
    opacity: .6;
    width: 180px;
    right: -80px;
    clip: rect(-6px,90px,14px,-6px);
    }

    #loadingbar dd {
      opacity: .6;
      width: 20px;
      right: 0;
      clip: rect(-6px,22px,14px,10px);
    }

    #loadingbar dd, #loadingbar dt {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      height: 2px;
      -moz-box-shadow: #b91f1f 1px 0 6px 1px;
      -ms-box-shadow: #b91f1f 1px 0 6px 1px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: #B91F1F 1px 0 6px 1px;
      box-shadow: #B91F1F 1px 0 6px 1px;
      -moz-border-radius: 100%;
      -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function (xmlHttpRequest) {
                    if ($("#loadingbar").length === 0) {
                        $("body").append("<div id='loadingbar'></div>")
                        $("#loadingbar").addClass("waiting").append($("<dt/><dd/>"));
                        $("#loadingbar").width((50 + Math.random() * 30) + "%");
                    }
                    //show the loading div here
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("#loadingbar").width("101%").delay(200).fadeOut(400, function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                    //remove the div here
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

    <div id="loadingbar"></div>


        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Me thinks you forgot an event handler ?

Comment: `press a button`..so you need to attach an event `onclick` to button..

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="" /> onclick wht to call?

Comment: OnClientClick="ajaxSetup" not work?

Comment: doesn't sound like you are even using ajax to submit...show the submit code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach an event `onclick` to button in order for it to load your progress Bar.Try this:

```
document.getElementById("Button1").onclick=demo; //event handler added to button

function demo(){
$.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function (xmlHttpRequest) {
                if ($("#loadingbar").length === 0) {
                    $("body").append("<div id='loadingbar'></div>")
                    $("#loadingbar").addClass("waiting").append($("<dt/><dd/>"));
                    $("#loadingbar").width((50 + Math.random() * 30) + "%");
                }
                //show the loading div here
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#loadingbar").width("101%").delay(200).fadeOut(400, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                //remove the div here
            }
        });

    }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QfgJ5/5/)